# How can set localization for a list of items in flutter? I am using easy_localization package

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

Suppose I have a list of item that's I want to have translations like -

```
List<Person> persons = [
 {name: 'a', profession: 'xxx', age: 24},
 {name: 'b', profession: 'xxx', age: 24},
 {name: 'c', profession: 'xxx', age: 24},
]
```

I want localization for the value's of the array.[Although for this example the values seems it can be anything, but in my use case it will be in the range of certain values]. In other language (typescript) for this kind of localization I just putted the whole list in the en.json file, and retreive this list through the localization library and use it(loop over it and use it). But for flutter (easy_localization package specially) if I try put a key value is json file as an list and trying to access it I am getting error(I guess the package only supports return type as string).

So what will be the best way to achieve this in flutter(Need to have a list of items that I can loop over). What I am currently doing is

In the translation file (en.json) -

```
{
 "professions": {
   "xxx": "xxx",
   "yyy": "yyy"
 },
 "age": {
   "20": "20",
   "21": "21"
 }
}
```

And in the dart file I am making that list(It's a constant list) and the values for the list item's key's I'm accessing through the localization json file(person.dart) -

```
List<Person> person = [
 {name: 'a'.tr(), professions: 'professions.xxx'.tr(), age: 'age.20'.tr()},
 {name: 'b'.tr(), professions: 'professions.yyy'.tr(), age: 'age.21'.tr()},
]
```

But can I achieve something like I don't have to create this list of items in the dart file, it will belong to the localization json file and I can create the list of items from the json file directly.

Or is there any other better way to handle this kind of situation, where I need a list of items but that items text will be through localization. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: I think you're using it wrong to get the values from the list. To get a localized profession you should use ````'professions'.tr('xxxx')````.  Check the example used on here https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization#-translate-tr to get the gender.

Comment: No, you can use this format also `'professions.xxx'.tr()`, the translation I am getting is correct, don't have any problem with the translation. I just wanted to know what will be better approach for list of items that i need translations.